# How to check if string contains special part

Tags: c#, regex, string

How I can check if my string has the value ".all" in. Example:

```
  string myString = "Hello.all";
```

I need to check if myString has .all in order to call other method for this string, any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: why not `myString.Contains(".all");`

Comment: To check if the string ends with _.all_ you can use `myString.EndsWith(".all")`

Comment: Using regex is likely an overkill here, just `myString.Contains(".all")` or `myString.EndsWith(".all")`.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Question you refer to is about character and not string so it's not exactly as this question.

Comment: @VladStryapko `Contains` method is working exactly the same for both  characters and strings.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov It doesn't mean the question is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `.Contains(".all")` on the string object:

```
if (myString.Contains(".all") 
{
    // your code to call the other method goes here
}
```

There is no need for regex to do that.

Optionally, as mentioned by @ZarX in comments, you can check if the string ends with your keyword with `.EndsWith(".all")`, which will return true if the string ends with your keyword.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `myString.Contains(".all")`

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use `IndexOf()`

```
var s = "Hello.all";
var a = s.IndexOf(".all", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If `a = -1` then no occurrences found
If `a = some number other than -1` you get the index (place in the string where it starts).
So `a = 5` in this case

Comment: Apart from storing the position of the occurence, is there any other addition using this method rather than using `Contains` or `EndsWith`?

Comment: @Asunez The TS did not state that it has to be in the end of the string, so `endsWith` is not the answer here. And if using `IndexOf` instead of `Contains` you have more control over the casing and culture settings

Comment: @Azurez If you look for source of string.cs here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs you will see that `Contains` is calling `IndexOf`